# Should qualified partial answers be deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-answers

Suppose we have a complex question like:

> Do Nation X and Nation Y both have freckled parliamentarians?

1. User *Mr.Foo* answers:

   > As a resident of Nation X, I know of seven freckled parliamentarians, namely: ....*etc.*
2. User *Mr.Bar* answers:

   > As a resident of Nation Y, I know of four freckled parliamentarians, namely: ....*etc.*

Should a moderator delete one or both of these answers, on the grounds that they each *fail to answer the question* of **both** nations?

Comment: Partial answers often indicate a question that is too broad. Ideally, your example question should be closed, edited to only be about a single nation and re-opened. Problem solved.

Comment: @yannis, Please post that as an answer.

Comment: A moderating example from a [deleted post](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/23667/is-president-trump-right-that-there-was-violence-on-both-sides-in-charlottesvi#comment81335_23674).  Unfortunately it's only viewable by users with 2000 points.

Comment: It is clear that the question is focused on violence by left-wing protestors. The answer only discusses violence by right-wing protestors. That is not a partial answer, that is a non-answer, and it was correctly deleted.

Comment: @yannis, Please generalize your comment as to what distinguishes such special cases, and post it as an answer.

Comment: It's not a special case. Your example is not a partial answer. It doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @yannis, Re _"doesn't answer **the** question at all"_:  yes, but only if we interpret *"the"* question to mean exclusively one side of it, so that an answer addressing the other side is redefined as invalid.  Which is something like [your own advice](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3571/should-qualified-partial-answers-be-deleted#comment8257_3571), but neglecting to first edit the Q. to specify only a single aspect.

Answer (score 8):

**No.**  Partial answers can stand.  They are useful.